# How to perform undersampling on numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have input and output features as numpy arrays of the below shapes

```
X=(1000, 180)
y=(1000, 180)
```

On the input feature set I want to apply undersampling using SMOTE and used the below code:

```
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
from imblearn.under_sampling import RandomUnderSampler

# define undersample strategy
undersample = RandomUnderSampler(sampling_strategy='majority')
# fit and apply the transform
X_over, y_over = undersample.fit_resample(X, y)
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.01, random_state=1)
```

but I am getting an error which says

```
ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (1000, 180) instead.
```

while running the below statement

```
X_over, y_over = undersample.fit_resample(X, y)
```

Afterwards, I updated the code as below:

```
# define undersample strategy
undersample = RandomUnderSampler(sampling_strategy='majority')
# fit and apply the transform
y_undersample  = y.ravel()
X_over, y_over = undersample.fit_resample(X, y_undersample)
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.01, random_state=1)
```

but then got another error saying

> ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of
> samples: [1000, 180000]

Please advise how can I fix this error?

Comment: How can the shape of your target variable `y` be `(1000, 180)`? That would mean you have 180 targets, wouldn't it? While just one is supported by sampling approaches (shape `(1000,)`)). I do not fully understand this. Please explain and/or provide a subset of your features and labels.

Comment: please see my question which is related to the same problem: 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72779242/how-to-generate-bio-tags-for-custom-entities-in-ner'