# Different BLIOU tags generated for same word in spaCy

Tags: python, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I have an annotated dataset below which contains different entities that are applicable to different sets of words in a document. Here is one of the sample document (out of 1000 documents) which contains the full text, the starting and ending position to locate an entity e.g. [426, 439, 'NO-CHEST-PAIN']

```
{'classes': ['FEMALE',
  'ASSOCIATED-SOB-OR-ASSOCIATED-SHORTNESS-OF-BREATH',
  'EPISODES-OF-HEART-RACING',
  'RECENT-VISIT-TO-EMERGENCY-DEPARTMENT-WITH-NEGATIVE-WORKUP',
  'NO-CHEST-PAIN',
  'NO-ILLICIT-DRUG-USE',
  'INCREASED-FREQUENCY-RECENTLY',
  'EPISODES-LAST-15-TO-30-MINUTES',
  'FEELS-HOT-OR-FEELS-CLAMMY',
  'EPISODE-OF-HAND-NUMBNESS-OR-EPISODE-OF-FINGER-NUMBNESS',
  'INCREASED-STRESS',
  '26-YEAR'],
 'annotations': [['Ms. Whelan is a 26 yo F with a 6 mo hx of heart palpitations that have been increasing in freq in the past 2 weeks. She was seen 2 weeks ago for similar symptoms with a w/u WNL. \r\n-The events last 12-30 min, are not assoc with anything particular, no alleviating or aggrevating factors. \r\n-She has assoc SOB, hot and then cold and clamy skin\r\n-Recently had numbness of fingertips on both hands during palpitation event \r\nROS: No dyspne, CP, skin, hair or wt changes. \r\nPMH: none\r\nPSH: None \r\nMeds: none \r\nAllergies: NKD\r\nFH: non contributory \r\nSH: 2 months unemployed, recently purchased a condo but is optomistic about her financial and occupational situation. Lives alone, sexual active with one partner, uses condoms. No alcohol, tobacco or drug use.',
   {'entities': [[16, 21, '26-YEAR'],
     [22, 23, 'FEMALE'],
     [48, 60, 'EPISODES-OF-HEART-RACING'],
     [76, 115, 'INCREASED-FREQUENCY-RECENTLY'],
     [120, 177, 'RECENT-VISIT-TO-EMERGENCY-DEPARTMENT-WITH-NEGATIVE-WORKUP'],
     [192, 206, 'EPISODES-LAST-15-TO-30-MINUTES'],
     [298, 307, 'ASSOCIATED-SOB-OR-ASSOCIATED-SHORTNESS-OF-BREATH'],
     [331, 336, 'FEELS-HOT-OR-FEELS-CLAMMY'],
     [357, 393, 'EPISODE-OF-HAND-NUMBNESS-OR-EPISODE-OF-FINGER-NUMBNESS'],
     [401, 418, 'EPISODES-OF-HEART-RACING'],
     [426, 439, 'NO-CHEST-PAIN'],
     [548, 567, 'INCREASED-STRESS'],
     [569, 595, 'INCREASED-STRESS'],
     [721, 752, 'NO-ILLICIT-DRUG-USE']]}]]}
```

On this dataset, I am further extracting BLIOU tags using spaCy

```
for text, annot in training_data['annotations']:
    doc=nlp(text)
    xx=([token.text for token in doc])
    yy=([token.pos_ for token in doc])
    tags=offsets_to_biluo_tags(doc, annot['entities'])
    sentence='Sentence:1'
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Sentence #':sentence,'Word': xx,'POS': yy,'Tag': tags})
```

which gives me the output as below

[image]

On analysing the dataset, I found that for the same word (present across different documents) different BLIOU tag is generated as below:
Is there any way how can I mitigate this problem and generate the same tag for a word across all the documents?

[image]

Comment: Closely related but not quite duplicate question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72779242/how-to-generate-bio-tags-for-custom-entities-in-ner/72781296#72781296

Answer (score -1):

The BILOU tag that's relevant for a token should be completely defined by the spans it's in, and based on the kinds of annotations you have, it's unsurprising that a specific word (especially a very general one like "pain") would have different tags in different contexts.

Why do you think it's a problem that the tag differs? I don't think you have a problem here.